# Deleted the Team Provisioning Profile:* in the Provisioning Portal, what to do?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, profile, provisioning

I accidentally deleted the Team Provisioning Profile:* in the Provisioning Portal, what should I do now? :/

Answer (score 11):

I have a MacBook with Xcode 4.2 installed.

I also, in the course of "getting acquainted" with the iOS Provisioning Portal and Xcode, removed the iOS Team Provisioning Profile:*.  I wasn't having any success getting it back, either by removing the device from Xcode Organizer and plugging it back in, or by removing and again creating the Provisioning Profile for my test app.  Here's what I did.

With the device connected to the computer, Ctrl-Click the device in Xcode Organizer, and select the option Add Device to Provisioning Profile.

Once this was complete, the iOS Team Provisioning Profile:* appeared in Xcode Organizer, it appeared on my device (Settings > General > Profiles), and it appeared in the iOS Provisioning Profile area on the developer.apple.com site.

Comment: FANTASTIC!!! I had been tearing my beard out with this problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Create it again by unlinking and relinking your device to the Xcode Organizer. Or better yet, create another profile manually in the provisioning portal.

Whichever you do, remember to check that the new profile appears on your device (**Settings > General > Profiles**) and that your apps are signed with it.

Comment: ok, I removed the iPhone from organizer and added it again, the new Team Provisioning Profile appears in General> Profiles, but Organizer says "Xcode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain"
What now?
Thanks!

Comment: @Val Kalinic: Are you on the same Mac where you first made the team provisioning profile? If not you need to regenerate it on that Mac. If you're alone, I think your developer certificates got busted as well, you may have to create them again. I'm not very certain on this one...

Comment: yep, my good ole MacBook :D
Create again? Like just revoke and redownload?
Thanks!

Comment: @Val Kalinic: Ah yes, I guess try that first, and if it's still not working you'll have to issue yourself a new certificate.

Comment: @BoltClock, done it, but Xcode still cant find a valid... Is there anything else I can do? If not, do I really need the Team Provisioning Profile?
I mean, I can use other profiles for testing an App on the Device and then switch to a Distribution profile before using Application Loader, am I wrong?
Will I be able to install iOS 5 without this profile?

Comment: If you don't need the Team Provisioning Profile, you can create another one of your own in the provisioning portal, and download and install it manually. You shouldn't need a provisioning profile to install iOS 5.

Comment: Thanks for the help man :)
I fixed it like this: In organizer > uncheck Automatic Device Provisioning, refresh, and chek it again! :)
Everything works perfect now :))
But can't then someone outside the Program install the beta iOS? o.O

Comment: @Vak Kalinic: Yeah, anyone with the installer can install it with iTunes or Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 4.6, Organizer > Teams > Refresh did it for me. None of the answers above seemed to help. Specifically, refreshing in the Profiles section or Add to Portal in the device section did not work.

This also, finally, managed to add devices to the Team profile that I had entered manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem. Mine expired and Renew doesn't work because it looks like the day it expires its gone from the provisioning portal. But, good news, just go to the Organizer with the device connected, right click "Provisioning Profiles" and do "Add device to Provisioning Portal" and it will do all the necessary steps to recreate the profile and all your previously provisioned apps are up and running again. All the other devices you have to do "Add" and it will just put the new profile on those devices without having to recreate anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I searched everywhere and tried everything and I still could not get Xcode to generate me a new team provisioning profile. Finally I read something in the Apple documentation that said something like:

"When you add a new device to the portal [through Xcode] Xcode will generate a wild card app ID and an iOS Team provisioning profile, if it does not already exist"

Re-registering my existing devices did not work. I had to find a device that was not already registered. Once I added this new device it did, finally, re-generate the profile. Here were the steps I took to *recreate* my team provisioning profile (NB: You should probably be the team agent)

1. In the provisioning portal delete your iOS Team Provisioning Profile, if it already exists.
2. In the provisioning portal delete your Wildcard App ID, if it already exists.
3. Open Xcode and go to the Organiser.
4. Plug in a new device that you have never registered before.
5. Right click on the device and select "Add Device to Provisioning Portal"

Hope that helps someone waste less time than I did.

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. I had deleted my iOS Team Provisioning Profile from my computer and when I went to the Apple Developer Portal, the iOS Team Provisioning Profile was there but invalid and I couldn't edit or download it. Deleting devices and re-adding devices didn't work and I didn't have a new device(!?) to register again with. This is what I had to do:

1. Go to the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action) and then click on Provisioning Profiles
2. Find the old iOS Team Provisioning Profile and delete it
3. Go to Xcode -> Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles and double check there is no reference to an iOS Team Provisioning Profile
4. If you have a device plugged in, check the Provisioning Profiles under that device and double check there is no reference to an iOS Team Provisioning Profile
5. This is the magic step I was missing. From the Organizer, go to the Editor menu and select 'Refresh From Developer Portal'.
6. Magically a new iOS Team Provisioning Profile was created in the Apple Developer Portal which I could just download and use again with my test apps to get them on device. I had to delete any reference to old provisioning profiles from my projects, restart Xcode etc. to get it be recognized again but that's standard practice right?

Hope that helps someone. I finally found that information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DevelopingAppsThatRequireCertificatesandProvisioning/DevelopingAppsThatRequireCertificatesandProvisioning.html) in the docs under one of the troubleshooting sections:

> To create the team provisioning profile using assets already in your account, open the Devices organizer in Xcode and select "Refresh from Developer Portal” from the Editor menu.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the answers in [Refresh devices in team provisioning profile managed by Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729193/refresh-devices-in-team-provisioning-profile-managed-by-xcode-7) , you can just delete and re-add the Apple ID in the Preferences->Accounts panel, which should regenerate the xcode-managed team provisioning profiles in the Developer Center. (Other answers here and elsewhere suggest to right-click provisioning profiles, which doesn't work for me, or apply to older versions of XCode for which the answers no longer apply.)

Answer (score 0):

In September 2015, I fixed this by launching Xcode 6 and creating a new project.  I followed this guidance from [Apple's troubleshooting documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html), and it fixed my problem:

> If a warning message and Fix Issue button appear below the Team pop-up
> menu in the General pane or in a section of the Capabilities pane in
> the project editor, read the message and click the Fix Issue button.

I now have a wildcard team provisioning profile back in the developer portal.