# How to regenerate Team Provisioning Profile?

Tags: provisioning, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program, provisioning-profile

I bought new iphone and tried to install one of my developing app on my new iphone bu tit didn't work. I accidentally deleted my team provisioning profile from apple developer portal. Now i can't regenerate it. And can't install developing app even on my old iphone. Before i could install it on my old iphone. It gives this error:

Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.yourcompany.YourApp' could not be found.

It happened after deleting team provisioning profile. How can i fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleted the Team Provisioning Profile:\* in the Provisioning Portal, what to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241568/deleted-the-team-provisioning-profile-in-the-provisioning-portal-what-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

I made a new provisioning profile with same app id. And changed bundle identifier in plist. It worked for me.